# RuntimeError: This event loop is already running aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

I want to make telegram bot to download TikTok videos. I need to download TikTok video using its URL. And after I send a message with link, it raises this error. How can I solve it? Is there any other way to download TikTok video, My code is below.

```
ERROR: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\scripts\saveassbot\bot.py", line 28, in text
    with TikTokApi() as api:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\TikTokApi\tiktok.py", line 159, in __init__
    self._initialize(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\TikTokApi\tiktok.py", line 205, in _initialize
    self._browser = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 618, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 578, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

Code:
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
    import logging
    import main
    import config
    from TikTokApi import TikTokApi
    
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    bot = Bot(token=config.token)
    dp = Dispatcher(bot)
    
    
    @dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
        # if(not BotDB.user_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        #    BotDB.add_user(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.username)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                               f'hello',
                               parse_mode="Markdown")
    
    
    @dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    async def text(message: types.Message):
        if message.text.startswith('https://vt.tiktok.com'):
            video_url = message.text
            with TikTokApi() as api:
                video = api.video(url=f"{video_url}")
    
                # Bytes of the TikTok video
                video_data = video.bytes()
    
                with open(f"{message.from_user.id}", "wb") as out_file:
                    out_file.write(video_data)
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[By the looks of it](https://github.com/davidteather/TikTok-Api/blob/21bd25c5628ea156ae30233d7b34b1ee518d4d40/TikTokApi/tiktok.py#L204-L209), the `TikTokApi` library is broken in the sense it can't be constructed if there's already an asyncio loop running (and there is, when you use `aiogram`).

You could see if "misusing" the API by initializing it at the start of your program, before you enter the aiogram loop, works:

```
# ...
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
tiktok_api = TikTokApi()
# ...
async def text(message: types.Message):
   # ...
   video = tiktok_api.video(...)
```

but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: So I tried but nothing changed